# Регулярное выражение: обрезать ссылку до домена (оставляя протокол)

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как с помощью регулярного выражения обрезать ссылку, до последнего слеша перед доменом (что бы остался протокол, протоколы попадаются разные http и https)?

Пример исходных данных:

```
http://site.com/catalog/rasprodazha/stenka-pod-televizor-bms000921415/
https://web.com/searchresults/v/1/5a13b980340c745ca1e7b24b/5a13bbaa340c745ca1e82bf2/2022-12-15
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
http://site.com
https://web.com
```

регулярку буду использовать в обычном блокноте (напр.: notepad++)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю использовать негативный просмотр назад на отсутствие символа `:` или `/` перед символом `/` далее ноль и более любых символов до конца строки.

В поле **Найти:** `(?<!:|/)/.*$`
В поле **Заменить на:** оставить пустоту

Должен быть установлен параметр поиска `Регулярные выражения` и отсутствовать параметр и новые строки.

[image: Notepad]

Comment: Спасибо, отлично работает!